# TIMEZONE set for specific country but we get UTC Time - how it can be?

Tags: linux, rhel, date, time, timezone

I have Linux red-hat 6.6 version
This machine was set for Israel time zone as the following

```
#  more /etc/sysconfig/clock
   ZONE="Israel"

   ls -ltr /etc/localtime
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Jul 17 12:06 /etc/localtime ->     /usr/share/zoneinfo/Israel
```

but what is very strange , in spite the GMT configured for Israel Time Zone  , we get UTC date??
as the following

```
  # date
  Mon Jul 18 17:24:19 UTC 201
```

In place to get the correct time as

```
 Mon Jul 18 20:31:59 IDT 2016
```

please advice How it can Be?

Comment: Check if your environment variable contain `TZ` variable?

Comment: please advice how to check?

Comment: `env | grep 'TZ='`

Comment: not get anything from output

Comment: [RHEL 6 Manually Change Time Zone](https://thornelabs.net/2013/04/25/rhel-6-manually-change-time-zone.html)  Don't forget to reboot.

Comment: I not completely agree because if you do ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles /etc/localtime , then the date command will show you the new timezone , no need reboot to the system